# A logic circuit with a NOT condition

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, logic-gates

I have the following problem to solve and Im a bit confused:

I have a ceramic factory that is based on a circuit with 4 outputs:

- timer that outputs "1" when the oven is on (timer)
- sensor that outputs "0" when temperature of the oven is too low
- sensor that outputs "0" when temperature of the oven is too high
- sensor that outputs "1" when ceramic is humid

Now I should find a function that outputs "on" on the following conditions:

- If the oven is on AND:

  1. temperature is between the correct interval
  2. temperature is above the limit BUT ceramic is humid
- If the oven is not on  BUT ceramic is humid.

From my understanding I have 3 different logic doors, them being:

- a) oven on(time = 1) and temperature is fine (sensor = 1)
- b) oven on(time = 1) , temperature above limit (sensor = 0) and ceramic is humid (Hum = 1)
- c) oven NOT on(time = 0) and ceramic is humid (Hum = 1)

I have tried to build the logic circuit to get the function but Im kinda stuck. On my c) variable, Time is 0 and Humidity must be 1 but there is no logic gate that supports this. Am I wrong?

Sorry but Im still learning!

[image: Circuit layout:]

Comment: @RonBeyer hum, so on my c) output that could solve the problem... but on my b) I also need to output with those 3 conditions (1, 0, 1) and there is no logic gate to do that. Shoud I split it?

Comment: trivial job for a microcontroller!

Comment: As mentioned: start using inverters. If you invert temp in (b) (1,0,1) it becomes (1,1,1) for which there is a gate. Time,hum (0,1) with Time inverted becomes (1,1).  etc.

Comment: @Oldfart I think I found a way of doing it - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORMQ3.png

Comment: That circuit corresponds with your a,b,c, equations, but I have **not** checked if your a,b,c are correct. I just assumed you did not make any mistakes there.

Comment: The proper way to design logic here would use a Truth Table with all inputs and outputs assigned a letter in X vs Y

Comment: Normally you have a thermostat and a safety overtemp cutout  so the algorithm regulates heat if undertemp and cuts out for safety on overtemp with another sensor. The humidity sensor determines when it is done within safety timer limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to do is draw a truth table. This will clarify your thinking and is much easier to understand than a list of bullet points.

*Table 1. The required functionality. 'X' is don't care.*

```
Timer   Above low Above high  Humidity
On      temp SP   temp SP     high       Out
-------+---------+----------+----------++-----
 1     | 1       | 1        | X        || 1
 X     | X       | 0        | 1        || 1
```

This has neatly reduced the problem to two lines. The two lines will require an OR gate to combine the logic.

Note that you don't need to check the LOW TEMP OK signal on line 2 as if if it is over the high temperature setpoint then it must be over the low temperature setpoint.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2MH93.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A possible solution.*

This uses four different types of logic gates. You can use [DeMorgan's Theorem and Laws](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/demorgan.html) to modify the logic to use fewer gate types.

Answer (score 0):

> Time is 0 and Humidity must be 1 but there is no logic gate that supports this. Am I wrong?

You're generally not going to find many IC's offering specifically an AND gate with one input inverted.

But there's no reason you can't make one by combining gates from two different IC's, by using a (C)PLD or by using MCU software.

Additionally, NAND and NOR are universal logic functions, in the sense that you can achieve any function by combining several such gates.  So you actually could implement such a function by clever use of multiple gates in a quad NAND or NOR package.

Hopefully this is an academic exercise, the control algorithm being considered is probably too simplistic for real-world use.  More suitable algorithms would point strongly towards the capability and tunability of a software implementation on a basic MCU.